# Kubernetes Job that can restart a pod or rollout restart deployment

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, kubernetes-cronjob

I have containerized app running on kubernetes which has volume mounted to efs. The volume contains a directory that gets updated with files on a periodic basis(eg. monthly). The update of files(zip and upzip) can be done by a CronJob. It's a big file and download and can take several minutes. The folder name after unzip is different for each month (eg. data_202001, data_202001, etc). I need to restart the pod (similar to executing a `kubectl rollout restart deployment/my-app`) once the unzip process is done so that I can restart the pod and run the init scripts to point it to the new directory/folder.

Basically, my challenge is to restart the pods. I need the app to be self-restarting without manual/human intervention. I tried having a `kubectl` in a docker container and see if I can execute this `kubectl` commands but run into permission issues so this is not an option for now.

Answer (score 0):

There is no single correct solution for your case. Actually, it can be done in many different ways. One of the approaches that seems quite reasonable is using an additional **sidecar container** (refer to this [section](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/#using-pods)), running in such `Pod`, which would watch the directory for updates and once it detects a change, it may call **kubernetes-api** (either using **kubectl** utility or directly from the code, using for that one of the [client libraries](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/client-libraries/), available for different programming languages) so that the whole `Pod` is restarted. Of course it would need to have configured for that a [`ServiceAccount`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-service-account/) bind to a specific role with a [`RoleBinding`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/#rolebinding-and-clusterrolebinding), which will allow it to perform required actions.
As you may expect, it can not be handled just on **kubernetes** level and you need an additional component that is responsible for this process. I think decoupling it from your main app is good approach, but it can be also integrated into your main container. Choosing the specific solution is up to you.

Comment: I was able to achieve this by creating a `CronJob` that runs the download in the initContainer and in the main container execute a `kubectl patch ...` command.

Comment: In such case you may consider posting it as an answer and describe your solution in detail.